# HOW TO QUERY NESTED XML DATA IN SNOWFLAKE separated by commas

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I want to remove all the tags and replace them with commas. I attempted to write some of the queries but had no success. Below is the sample data I shared and the output I need.

Here is the sample data :-

```
<TAGS>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_ID>19</TAG_ID>
    <NAME>Ct</NAME>
  </TAG>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_ID>104</TAG_ID>
    <NAME>Ntt</NAME>
  </TAG>
</TAGS>
```

**Needed Output**

19,Ct,104,Ntt

Comment: Any approach to work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
select LISTAGG( f.VALUE,',')
from values 
('<TAGS>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_ID>19</TAG_ID>
    <NAME>Ct</NAME>
  </TAG>
  <TAG>
    <TAG_ID>104</TAG_ID>
    <NAME>Ntt</NAME>
  </TAG>
</TAGS>') tmp(mydata),
lateral flatten( parse_xml(mydata):"$",  RECURSIVE => TRUE ) f
WHERE f.KEY = '$' and NOT IS_ARRAY(f.VALUE);
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error.
String '(LISTAGG result)' is too long and would be truncated

Comment: Then you need to break your data into smaller chunks, cause it means your end result does not fit into 16MB.

Comment: Actually the xml i shared it belongs to one cell means it belongs to one particular row and each row has the "xml type of data
It is something like this
row1            row 2
some data    xml data
some data1  xml data 2,So while breaking this xml data ,we are getting all data in one row

Comment: @RohitJha I wrote the query based on the limited data you provided. In real life, you should have other columns that you can use for grouping etc